# Understanding the variance of random effects in lmer() models

Tags: r, mixed-model, random-effects-model, lme4-nlme

I'm having trouble understanding the output of my `lmer()` model. It is a simple model of an outcome variable (Support) with varying State intercepts / State random effects:

```
mlm1 <- lmer(Support ~ (1 | State))
```

The results of `summary(mlm1)` are:

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML 
Formula: Support ~ (1 | State) 
   AIC   BIC logLik deviance REMLdev
 12088 12107  -6041    12076   12082
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance  Std.Dev.
 State    (Intercept) 0.0063695 0.079809
 Residual             1.1114756 1.054265
Number of obs: 4097, groups: State, 48

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)  0.13218    0.02159   6.123
```

I take it that the variance of the varying state intercepts / random effects is `0.0063695`. But when I extract the vector of these state random effects and calculate the variance

```
var(ranef(mlm1)$State)
```

The result is: `0.001800869`, considerably smaller than the variance reported by `summary()`.

As far as I understand it, the model I have specified can be written:

$y_i = \alpha_0 + \alpha_s + \epsilon_i, \text{ for } i = \{1, 2, ..., 4097\}$

$\alpha_s \sim N(0, \sigma^2_\alpha), \text{ for } s = \{1, 2, ..., 48\}$

If this is correct, then the variance of the random effects ($\alpha_s$) should be $\sigma^2_\alpha$. Yet these are not actually equivalent in my `lmer()` fit.

Comment: Do you have some knowledge about the way parameters are estimated with `lmer()`? It seems that you *postulate* that $\sigma^2_\alpha$ is estimated by the empirical variance of the estimated random effects $\hat\alpha_s$. The description of your model is not clear (perharps $y_i$ should be $y_{is}$). Is it a balanced design ?

Comment: [Here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69882/why-computing-the-variance-of-the-extracted-random-effect-using-ranef-is-not-t) is a very similar question, with a somehow different answer

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a classic one way anova.  A very short answer to your question is that the variance component is made up of two terms.

$$\hat{\sigma}^2_{\alpha}=E\left[\frac{1}{48}\sum_{s=1}^{48} \alpha_s^2\right]= \frac{1}{48}\sum_{s=1}^{48}\hat{ \alpha }_s^2 +\frac{1}{48}\sum_{s=1}^{48}var(\hat{ \alpha }_s)$$

So the term you computed is the first term on the rhs (as random effects have mean zero).  The second term depends on whether REML of ML is used, and the the sum of squared *standard errors* of your random effects.

Comment: OK, got it! So, the sum of the squared SEs of the REs -- `1/48 * sum((se.ranef(mlm1)$State)^2)` -- is `0.004557198`. The variance of the point estimates of the REs (obtained, as above, using `var(ranef(mlm1)$State)`) is `0.001800869`. The sum is `0.006358067`, which is the variance reported using `summary()` on the `lmer()` model above, to 4 or 5 digits at least. Many thanks @probability

Comment: For those looking to this answer and the comment for help, note that nomad545 has also made use of the `arm` R package for the `se.ranef()` function.

Comment: @probabilityislogic: Can you provide some more detail how that equation was calculated? Specifically, how was the second equality achieved? Also, shoudn't there be a hat  on the alpha after the first equality?

Comment: @user1357015 - one way to see this is to look at the gradient of the (marginal) log likelihood after integrating out the random effects.  That is, differentiate the likelihood $ Y\sim Normal (1_n\alpha_0,\Sigma) $ where $\Sigma=I_n\sigma^2_e+\sigma^2_{\alpha} ZZ^T$ is the "unconditional" variance of Y.  If you do this (plus using some manipulations) you get the above equality.  The second equality follows because $ E (\alpha_s)=0$ (under the model) meaning $ var (\alpha_s)=E (\alpha_s^2) $

Comment: I may be mistaken, but in the post by @probabilityislogic, it seems that "first term on the rhs" should be "second term on the rhs," and that "second term" should be "first term." The comment from nomad545 lends some support to this interpretation.