# Why computing the variance of the extracted random effect (using ranef) is not the same as the output from lme?

Tags: r, mixed-model

I am applying a mixed model to predict tumor progression (y) using tumor volume (x) as the fixed effect and center ($i=1,...10$) as random intercept. The model can be written as:
$$y_{ij}=\alpha+\beta x_{ij}+b_{i}+\epsilon_{ij}$$

I used the `lme()` function in R:

```
fit1 <- lme(PD ~ log(Volume), random = ~1 | CenterID, data=Data)
```

The result shows that the standard deviation of the random intercept is 0.079. Thus $b_{i}$ follows a normal distribution $N(0,0.079)$.

In the meantime, I can extract the random intercept by applying `ranef(fit1)`. This gives a list of $b_{i}$ corresponding to each center. Then I compute the standard of this vector.

```
sd(ranef(fit1)[[1]])
```

I would expect that it gives similar result as 0.079. However, it is far different.

Can someone tell me why `sd(ranef(fit1)[[1]])` gives different result than the model output `VarCorr(fit1)`? What is exactly the relation between `ranef(fit1)` and `VarCorr(fit1)`?

Comment: The same question is asked [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68106/understanding-the-variance-of-random-effects-in-lmer-models), but a different answer is given.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`VarCorr()` here provides the variance estimate of the random intercept by REML, but `sd(ranef(fit1)[[1]])` shows the standard deviation of the empirical Bayesian estimates of the random intercept. In other words, say we have parameter $\sigma$, `VarCorr()` gives us the estimate $\hat \sigma$; we can generate a random sample based on $\hat \sigma$, and then calculate the standard deviation of the random sample by `sd()`.

The two would be different since the result by `sd()` is an estimate of the result by `VarCorr()`. The similarity depends on the data set, and the two are similar when tested with the `Orthodont` example in `lme()`.

```
> summary(fit1 <- lme(distance ~ age, random = ~1 | Subject, data=Orthodont))
Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | Subject
        (Intercept) Residual
StdDev:    2.114724 1.431592

> sd(ranef(fit1)[[1]])
[1] 2.003087
```