# Interpretation of various output of "lmer" function in R

Tags: r, self-study, mixed-model, random-effects-model, lme4-nlme

```
library(lme4)
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy)
```

The notation `(Days | Subject)` says to allow the intercept and `Days` to vary randomly for each level of `Subject` .

Can you please explain me the result of the following commands ?

```
attr(summary(fm1)$varcor$Subject,"stddev")
(Intercept)        Days 
 24.740448    5.922133 

c(sd(ranef(fm1)$Subject[,1]),sd(ranef(fm1)$Subject[,2]))
[1] 21.595943  5.455217

summary(fm1)$sigma
[1] 25.59182

residuals(summary(fm1))

sd(residuals(summary(fm1)))
[1] 0.9183965
```

**What is the INTERPRETATION of the results found from various commands?**

That is , if one asks me what is the meaning of the results that you have found from `sd(ranef(fm1)$Subject[,1])`  and `attr(summary(fm1)$varcor$Subject,"stddev")[1]` ? Both are standard deviation of `Intercept` but of course there is difference between these two results . But I don't know what is this ?

In `?getMe` , it is said that from `summary(fm1)$sigma` , we found residual standard error . But why doesn't the result match with `sd(residuals(summary(fm1)))` ?

Also , In `summary(fm1)$varcor` there is value 0.066 under the column `Corr` . Does it mean correlation between two random effects `(Intercept)` and `Days` is 0.066 ?

Any help is appreciated . Thank you .

Comment: You probably want to calculate `sd(residuals(fm1))` and not `sd(residuals(summary(fm1))`.

Answer (score 2):

`attr(summary(fm1)$varcor$Subject,"stddev")[1]` gives you the estimated standard deviation of your random intercepts. This is the square-roots of the first main diagonal element of your estimate for the random effects variance-matrix $G$ (in [Wikipedia's notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_model#Definition)). You get $\hat{G}$ directly with `VarCorr(fm1)$Subject[,]`. With `sd(ranef(fm1)$Subject[,1])` you manually calculate the standard deviation from your estimated random intercepts. A fundamental difference is, that $\hat{G}$ estimates a population parameter, and `sd(ranef(fm1)$Subject[,1])` a parameter in *a subset* of the population. The same for `25.59182 = summary(fm1)$sigma` vs. `sd(residuals(fm1)) = 23.50343` (and not `sd(residuals(summary(fm1))`! I would say, this in an error in your code).

---

Yes, `0.066` is the correlation between the random effects.